# Mongoose .find() returning 200 response and empty array when there is no matching results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to add a layer of validation to my query by checking that the query returns something before I send a response. My problem is that when I test this with Postman, I am getting a 200 response with an empty array returned, even though there are no records in my collection at all.

```
router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    Appointment.find({ user: req.user.id })
      .populate("user", ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone"])
      .then(appointments => {
        if (!appointments) {
          // if the user id is not there, or if the appointments array is empty
          errors.noappointments = "You do not have any appointments booked";
          return res.status(404).json(errors);
        }
        res.json(appointments);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
  }
);
```

Comment: You need to add an extra condition in your if statement that checks if the appointments array is empty i.e if(!appointments || appointments.length == 0)

Comment: I have done this and weirdly it then returns an empty object rather than the error message

Comment: You need to of course chain the exec() method after the populate() method to get a promise

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are expecting a `real` promise. [exec gives you that](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises):

```
router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    Appointment.find({ user: req.user.id })
      .populate("user", ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone"])
      .exec()
      .then(appointments => {
        if (!appointments.length) {
          // if the user id is not there, or if the appointments array is empty
          errors.noappointments = "You do not have any appointments booked";
          return res.status(404).json(errors);
        }
        res.json(appointments);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
  }
);
```

See if this would work.

Comment: This does not make any difference :(